# What is meaning of "よ—ん"

Tags: meaning, slang

I only know that "よん" is means "four" (kanji: 四)

Some reference is [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puyo_Puyo~n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puyo_Puyo%7En) where is also "よ—ん" written.

Words and example:

うわ—い! かったよ—ん! (Source: Kingyo Chuuihou! 2 - Gyopi-chan o Sagase! - in-game conversation, after player winning one of the mini-games [Wapiko conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqERA.jpg)). Word without "よ—ん" = できたよ / with "よ—ん" = できたよ—ん ; 終わったよ = 終わったよ—ん.

Comment: In what kind of context?

Comment: Example of word and sentence:                                              "うわ—い!  かったよ—ん!                                                                Word without "よ—ん"  = できたよ / with "よ—ん" = できたよ—ん ; 終わったよ = 終わったよ—ん

Comment: Can you add to the question? Where did you see it, who was saying it, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's nothing more than a comical or vigorous variant of the sentence-end よ. A few people use it in very informal situations. "ーん" means nothing, but is added for emphasis. It may be analogous to saying "okey-dokey" instead of "okay".